# sql server query not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I'm coming from the Oracle world and I do not have much experience on SQL Server.
Can someone tell me why the inner section of this query is not working? 
I tried different options and none of them seem to work:

```
select EventType, sum(Executed), sum(TriggeredScenarios), sum(OpenAlerts),sum(TotalAlerts)
from (
      select id, 
            'myEvent' as [EventType],
             TriggeredScenarios,
             Executed,
                  TotalAlerts = (select sum(cnt) as [TotalCount] 
                                             -- it breaks from here 
                                             from (select count(*) as [cnt]
                                                            from [myAlert1] aa, [Alert] bb
                                                            where aa.EventType = EventType
                                                              and aa.EventId = id
                                                              and aa.AlertId = bb.id 
                                                              and bb.DetectionAlertType = 'myAlert1'
                                            -- until here 
                                            UNION 
                                            select count(*) as [cnt]
                                                            from [myAlert2] aa, [Alert] bb
                                                            where aa.EventType = EventType
                                                              and aa.EventId = id
                                                              and aa.AlertId = bb.id 
                                                              and bb.DetectionAlertType = 'myAlert2'
                                                      ) aa),
             OpenAlerts = (select sum(cnt) as [TotalAlerts] 
                                          from ( select count(*) as [cnt]
                                                      from [Alert] aa, [myAlert1] bb
                                                where aa.currentstateid not in (select intStateID 
                                                                                                   from _AlertStates 
                                                                                                   where strGroupName like (N'AlertsClosed%')
                                                                                                )
                                                      and bb.EventType = EventType
                                                and bb.EventId = id
                                                      and bb.AlertId = aa.id
                                                      and aa.DetectionAlertType = 'myAlert1' 
                                             UNION 
                                             select count(*) as [cnt]
                                                      from [Alert] aa, [myAlert2] bb
                                                where aa.currentstateid not in (select intStateID 
                                                                                                   from _AlertStates 
                                                                                                   where strGroupName like (N'AlertsClosed%')
                                                                                                )
                                                      and bb.EventType = EventType
                                                and bb.EventId = id
                                                      and bb.AlertId = aa.id
                                                      and aa.DetectionAlertType = 'myAlert2' 
                                                ) aa )              
         from [myEvent]
         where [Timestamp] >= '11/26/2012'
           AND [Timestamp] <  '11/27/2012'
      UNION
      select id, 
                  'myEvent2' as [EventType],
             TriggeredScenarios,
             Executed,
                  TotalAlerts = (select sum(cnt) as [TotalCount] 
                                             from (select count(*) as [cnt]
                                                            from [myAlert1] aa, [Alert] bb
                                                            where aa.EventType = EventType
                                                              and aa.EventId = id
                                                              and aa.AlertId = bb.id 
                                                              and bb.DetectionAlertType = 'myAlert1'
                                            UNION 
                                            select count(*) as [cnt]
                                                            from [myAlert2] aa, [Alert] bb
                                                            where aa.EventType = EventType
                                                              and aa.EventId = id
                                                              and aa.AlertId = bb.id 
                                                              and bb.DetectionAlertType = 'myAlert2'
                                                      ) aa),
             OpenAlerts = (select sum(cnt) as [TotalAlerts] 
                                          from ( select count(*) as [cnt]
                                                      from [Alert] aa, [myAlert1] bb
                                                where aa.currentstateid not in (select intStateID 
                                                                                                   from _AlertStates 
                                                                                                   where strGroupName like (N'AlertsClosed%')
                                                                                                )
                                                      and bb.EventType = EventType
                                                and bb.EventId = id
                                                      and bb.AlertId = aa.id
                                                      and aa.DetectionAlertType = 'myAlert1' 
                                             UNION 
                                             select count(*) as [cnt]
                                                      from [Alert] aa, [myAlert2] bb
                                                where aa.currentstateid not in (select intStateID 
                                                                                                   from _AlertStates 
                                                                                                   where strGroupName like (N'AlertsClosed%')
                                                                                                )
                                                      and bb.EventType = EventType
                                                      and bb.EventId = id
                                                      and bb.AlertId = aa.id
                                                      and aa.DetectionAlertType = 'myAlert2' 
                                                ) aa )              
         from [myEvent2]
         where [Timestamp] >= '11/26/2012'
           AND [Timestamp] <  '11/27/2012'
            )
group by EventName
```

Any help please?

Comment: um, formatting. and, perhaps more importantly, what do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Can you define 'not working' and can you format your query better?

Comment: Define `not working`. Help us help you.

Comment: I just formatted the code, it's easier to read now.

Comment: @user1932303: we want to help, but first you need to tell us what is wrong with the query - isn't returning the number of expected rows? Please edit your question and add more detail

Answer (score 4):

This is the section that you have marked as not working:

```
select count(*) as [cnt]
from [myAlert1] aa, [Alert] bb
where aa.EventType = EventType and
      aa.EventId = id and
      aa.AlertId = bb.id and
      bb.DetectionAlertType = 'myAlert1'
```

First, it is *very* bad form to put join conditions in the `where` clause rather than the `on` clause.  So, let me rewrite this as:

```
select count(*) as [cnt]
from [myAlert1] aa join
     [Alert] bb
     on aa.AlertId = bb.id
where aa.EventType = EventType and
      aa.EventId = id and
      bb.DetectionAlertType = 'myAlert1'
```

As written, this is "interpreted" as:

```
select count(*) as [cnt]
from [myAlert1] aa join
     [Alert] bb
     on aa.AlertId = bb.id
where aa.EventType = aa.EventType and  -- because there is no bb.EventType
      aa.EventId = bb.id and           -- because there is no aa.id
      bb.DetectionAlertType = 'myAlert1'
```

The link between EventId and bb.Id would probably prevent any rows from returns -- or at least, you would get fewer rows.

I suspect that `EventType` and `id` are intended to be PL/SQL variables.  If so, these would be written as:

```
select count(*) as [cnt]
from [myAlert1] aa join
     [Alert] bb
     on aa.AlertId = bb.id
where aa.EventType = @EventType and
      aa.EventId = @id and
      bb.DetectionAlertType = 'myAlert1'
```

Comment: Or, if they are columns in `MyEvent` (meaning that we are dealing with correlated subqueries), they should be prefixed with `MyEvent.`: `aa.EventType = MyEvent.EventType`, `aa.EventId = MyEvent.id`.